# Pass command line arguments in lua using java

Tags: java, lua

I am trying to trigger lua script from java using below code and it is working fine.

```
Globals globals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
LuaValue chunk = globals.loadfile("com/example/hello.lua");
chunk.call();
```

Now I want to pass command line arguments to my lua script, can someone help mw with the code how to pass command line argument to lua file from java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using LuaJ. First, Lua "chunks" are just special functions which get their arguments in the `...` vararg. `hello.lua` might look as follows:

```lua
local arg1, arg2 = ...
print("arg1", arg1, "arg2", arg2)
```

Using Lua's `loadfile`, you could pass arguments simply as function arguments when executing the loaded chunk:

```lua
local chunk = assert(loadfile"hello.lua") -- compile & load the file, do not run it
chunk("first arg", "second arg") -- run the file with two args
```

Your current Java code calls `chunk.call()` without any arguments, which would be equivalent to `chunk()` in Lua. You can use the [`invoke`](http://luaj.org/luaj/3.0/api/org/luaj/vm2/LuaValue.html#invoke(org.luaj.vm2.LuaValue%5B%5D)) method to pass a list of `LuaValue` arguments:

Just replace `chunk.call();` with

```java
chunk.invoke(new LuaValue[] {LuaValue.valueOf("first argument"), LuaValue.valueOf("second argument")});
```

to invoke the chunk with two arguments equivalent to the invokation in the above Lua example.